# Scala for-comprehension type inference

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

The next code

```
  def f(chars: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = chars match {
    case Nil => List(Nil)
    case x :: xs => for {
      v <- f(xs)
    } yield List(x) :: v
  }
```

gives the error message

```
- type mismatch;  found   : List[List[Any]]  required: List[List[Char]]
```

Please help me understand why 'for' chooses the most general Any instead of Char here? What topic in language spec should I read? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The result, you are `yielding` is a mix of `List[List[List[Char]]]` and `List[List[Char]]`. Scala upcasts that to `List[List[Any]]`. For your case either of the following will do the job:

```
scala>  def f(chars: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = chars match {
     |     case Nil => List(Nil)
     |     case x :: xs => for {
     |       v <- f(xs)
     |     } yield x :: v
     |   }
f: (chars: List[Char])List[List[Char]]

scala>  def f(chars: List[Char]): List[List[Char]] = chars match {
     |     case Nil => List(Nil)
     |     case x :: xs => for {
     |       v <- f(xs)
     |     } yield List(x) ++ v
     |   }
f: (chars: List[Char])List[List[Char]]
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is `List(x)` -- it needs to be `x`.

First, `v` iterates over the results of `f(xs)`, and `f` returns `List[List[Char]]`. That means the result will be `List[X]`, where `X` is the type returned by `yield`.

The type of `v` is `List[Char]`, since it is iterating over the contents of `f(xs)`. So we have to figure out the type of `List(x) :: v`, which is prepending a `List[Char]` on a `List[Char]`. It is *not* concatenating them: it is adding a list to a list containing only characters. The resulting list will have both `Char` and `List[Char]` in it.

Since the only type that satisfy both is `Any`, then `X` will be `Any` and the result of the for-comprehension `List[Any]`.